# Check for values with same key in a list of key-value pairs

Tags: java, dictionary, key-value

Let's say I have a list containing some key-value pairs, and an array containing a number of value.

```
public boolean hasSameKey(List<Map.Entry<Key, Value>> list, Value ... values) {
    return ?;
}
```

What I would like to check is that if all values in `values` have an entry in `list` with *the same key*.

**Edit** 
To clarify, each key in the list may have keys with several values

Comment: If it is a `Map` why aren't you using `Map<Key, Value>` ?

Comment: Do you mean that in map there already exists one key for each of values or that each of values has the same key?

Comment: @AdamArold - Map<Key, Value> can only store one value per key.

Comment: Since `Map.Entry` is package private you cannot manipulate it directly.

Comment: @Theodor Your model **is not a map**. It is just a list of key-value pairs. Calling it a map confuses everyone who reads this. Second, what you have is normally implemented as a **multimap**: a regular map with list-typed value.

Comment: @Theodor. Then you need: - `Map<Key, List<Value>>`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik sorry, that was confusing, fixed that in question.

Comment: So, array is a subset of List or opposite?

Comment: Yeah Map<Key, List<Value>> was of course the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I get from your question, I would first change your method signature a little to take `Map<Key, List<Value>>` as first parameter.

Then you can proceed like this: -

```
public boolean hasSameKey(Map<Key, List<Value>> map, Value... values) {

    for (Key key: map.keySet()) {
        if (map.get(key).containsAll(Arrays.asList(values))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

- `map.get(key)` - Gets the `List<Value>` for that corresponding key.
- [`List#containsAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method checks whether all the elements in a particular `collection` is in that list or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using a multimap like Rohit Jain suggested: `Map<Key, List<Value>>` you could do this:

```
public boolean hasSameKey(Map<Key, List<Value>> multimap, Value ... values) {
    for(Key key : multimap.keySet()) {
        if (map.get(key).containsAll(Arrays.asList(values))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This way you could check whether all of your `Value`s existed in a `List` in the `Map` or not.